# What is the time complexity of initializing a 2-D matrix?

Tags: algorithm, matrix, complexity-theory, time-complexity, multidimensional-array

I would like to initialize the matrix to all 0 values. Is the complexity O(1) or O(n)?

Comment: Apart from the trivial approach, another approach would be to store a "default value variable". Then, when you access a cell in the matrix for a first time, use the value in that variable. This could be a good solution for some matrix structures. This would make initialization O(1).

Comment: you mean initially I set a variable to 0 and tell every matrix element to point that variable? How is it different than assigning them all to 0?

Comment: Consider for example a case where your matrix is going to be sparse, i.e. most cells will have the same value. Now instead of saving the whole matrix you just need to store values that are different from the default value. Obviously the implementation details matter here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, if initialization complexity is a problem, and further matrix access is ordered, you can:

1. have an additional data structure to track WHAT matrix elements (rows or columns or even cells) are initialized;
2. lazily initialize elements only as you access them.

This approach might have no more complexity in matrix initialization than you have in the further processing.

Comment: OTOH, if the matrix is dense, `memset()` should be fine compared to any other processing, and if it's sparse, there are better data structures to hold it than a 2D array.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the meaning of `N`

- If `N` is the number of rows and columns in a square matrix, then the complexity is `O(N^2)`
- If `N` is the total number of elements in the matrix (i.e. `N = R*C`, where `R` is the number of rows and `C` is the number of columns) then the complexity is `O(N)`.